# Please explain how to work with NPM Missing script: "start"

Tags: npm

```
C:\Users\admin9>npm install <package.json>
Ошибка в синтаксисе команды.

C:\Users\admin9>npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\admin9\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-08T03_51_54_747Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\admin9>npm starts
Unknown command: "starts"

Did you mean one of these?
    npm star # Mark your favorite packages
    npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
    npm start # Start a package

To see a list of supported npm commands, run:
  npm help

C:\Users\admin9>yarn start
yarn run v1.22.19
warning package.json: No license field
error Command "start" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this commnd.
```

Unable to start npm ?

Please help me.Can't even start with Yarn

Comment: It's saying there is no `start` script in your `package.json`. Are you sure there is one?

Answer (score -1):

check the project `packege.json` file it seems there are no start script
so you should add `"start":"node index.js"` to the scripts
and change `index.js` to the name of the main file in your project